# Can someone please tell me what 工艺鞋 are？

Tags: meaning

工艺鞋

I think this refers to some kind of decorative shoes which are actually never worn, but I'm not sure. Why would you want to buy shoes you never wear?

Comment: iciba and webpages for 工艺  might suggest ＂handcrafted＂ for 工艺 in the present case（although there is 手工，手艺），cf。artistic handicrafts for 工艺品

Comment: to justify preceding comment some users might argue that 工艺 refers to the manufacturing method and correspondingly＂craft＂ may imply the concept of art，为了证明上面的评论有理，一些用户可能会认为＂工艺＂指的是制造方法而同样 craft，这词语很可能包含艺术的概念

Answer (score 1):

Well, to be frank, I am afraid you can not find this "工艺鞋" directly in Chinese dictionaries, so you can take this word as a definition which is not very clearly defined. I have searched on line I can show you several pics, they are all called "工艺鞋". However, as you can see, slippers, sandal, boots.... and from manmade to machine made.....  so you can imagine "工艺鞋" basically they are 'shoes'. If you wanna define it more precisely, they are  artistic temperamental shoes. I hope this can help you. I am not an English native speaker, but I tried my best. cheers.

[image: 工艺鞋01]

[image: 工艺鞋02]

[image: 工艺鞋03]

[image: 工艺鞋04]

[image: 工艺鞋05]

[image: 工艺鞋06]

[image: 工艺鞋07]

[image: 工艺鞋08]

Comment: Very good, thank you very much for your trouble!